# iOS: Create calendar with uneditable events?

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

From an app, is there a way to programmatically create a calendar with events that are uneditable? Or, what is the best way to achieve this as close as possible?

For example, Facebook events have a unique "Event Details" screen with their custom details. The user cannot edit the event from iCal, but instead have to click "View on Facebook".

[image]

1) I've explored creating local calendars and iCloud calendars but the user can easily edit the events and the calendars, including removing them, from iCal.

2) From the app, I cannot seem to create a new EKSource to have total control of the calendars I create in that source. Creating a new calendar in the existing CalDAV source also doesn't make it appear.

3) The EKCalendar class has an allowsContentModifications property, but it is readonly and cannot be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official response from Apple Developer Technical Support:

> Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there
>   is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the
>   currently shipping system configurations.

So as of right now there isn't a way to do this.